# how to get attribute name in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

could you please tell me how to get attribute value in xslt ?I have one xml .I need to parse this xml .I want to get class name of **blockquote**.I don't know that is postion of blockquote , but it comes inside the article tag

I tried like this

**xml**

```
<amp_articleshow >

<article >

    <arttextnew>
        <page>
            <div class="section1">
                <div class="Normal">
                    Dipika Kakar and
                    <keyword keytype="UnKnown" smid="0" usetype="2" keywordseo="Shoaib-Ibrahim">Shoaib Ibrahim</keyword>
                    are currently seen showing off their dancing skills on
                    <keyword keytype="UnKnown" smid="0" usetype="2" keywordseo="Nach-Baliye-8">Nach Baliye 8</keyword>
                    and are one of the judges' favourite jodis.
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Shoaib and Dipika are working really hard for their performances and have been giving their 100% to it.
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Shoaib, who had earlier played the role of Prem on Sasural Simra Ka, crossed 100k followers on Instagram and the actor has been overwhelmed.
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <strong>READ ALSO:</strong>
                    <br/>
                    <a class="inline-read" href="http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tv/news/hindi/nach-baliye-8-dipika-kakar-and-shoaib-ibrahims-hum-dil-de-chuke-moment/articleshow/58611440.cms">
                        <strong>
                            Nach Baliye 8: Dipika Kakar and Shoaib Ibrahim's 'Hum Dil De Chuke' moment
                        </strong>
                    </a>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    He posted a video thanking his fans. He captioned it saying "#100K Followers! Can't believe I crossed this milestone. Thank you so much guys for all this love. Couldn't have done without you!#LoveYouGuys #SoHappy"
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned="" data-instgrm-version="7" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);">
                        <div style="padding:8px;">
                            <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;">
                                <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;">
                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BT_zxpgBIgO/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">
                                    #100K Followers! Can't believe I crossed this milestone. Thank you so much guys for all this love. Couldn't have done without you!#LoveYouGuys #SoHappy
                                </a>
                            </p>
                            <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">A post shared by shoaib Ibrahim (@shoaib2087) on</p>
                            <time datetime="2017-05-12T15:17:19+00:00" style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;">May 12, 2017 at 8:17am PDT</time>
                        </div>
                    </blockquote>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Shoaib is currently seen in 'Koi Laut Ke Aaya Hai' opposite Surbhi Jyotii, while Dipika was last seen on Colors' 'Sasural Simar Ka'.
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    This is the first time ever that they will appear together on a reality show. The duo have been dating each other for quite some time now and plan to tie the knot in January next year.
                </div>
            </div>
        </page>
    </arttextnew>


</article>

</amp_articleshow>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="amp_articleshow">
     <xsl:value-of select="//./article/descendant::blockquote[@class]"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Expected output** ::
**instagram-media**

Comment: Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="amp_articleshow">
   <xsl:value-of select="//./article/descendant::blockquote/@class"/>
</xsl:template>
```

That's actually a question about XPath.
In XPath `/foo[@bar]` selects an element `foo` that has an attribute `bar` but it does not give you the value of `bar` which is what you want in your case.
To get the value of an attribute just change the query to `/foo/@bar` which indeed gives you the value of `foo`.
Here's a good link that shows how node [selection works](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//blockquote/@class"/>
```

Note that in XSLT 1.0 this will return the class of the **first** blockquote in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Predicates [] will check that bolckquote having class attribute means it will return the blockquote value which have class attribute.

```
blockquote[@class]
```

If you want to get the @class value you should go like:

```
blockquote/@class
```